# Onclick outside of div, hide the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide the div `#startMnu` when the user clicks out of the div named `.startBtn`. I can't get this to work, using this tutorial https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/tHCUB/ , for wherever I click, it says that it's outside the box.

```
$(".startBtn").click(function() { 
    $(".startBtn").fadeToggle(200); 
    $("#startMnu").toggle(200); 
}); 

$("body").clickOff(function() {       
    alert('clickOff'); 
});
```

These last lines of code are the only that have changed from the javascript part in the jsfiddle.

I'm trying to make a menu, where you can click the menu button, to open it, and close it either by clicking the button again, or clicking out of the div. Right now, the alert pops up wherever I click. Ideas?

Edit:

```js
//Effects.js
$(function() {
  $(".startBtn").click(function() {
    $(".startBtn").fadeToggle(200);
    $("#startMnu").toggle(200);
  });
});
$.fn.clickOff = function(callback, selfDestroy) {
  var clicked = false;
  var parent = this;
  var destroy = selfDestroy || true;

  parent.click(function() {
    clicked = true;
  });

  $(document).click(function(event) {
    if (!clicked) {
      callback(parent, event);
    }
    if (destroy) {
      //parent.clickOff = function() {};
      //parent.off("click");
      //$(document).off("click");
      //parent.off("clickOff");
    };
    clicked = false;
  });
};

$(".startBtn").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $("#startMnu").toggle();
});

$("body").click(function() {
  $("#startMnu").hide();
});
```

```css
/* effects.css */

#startBtn {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all ease 200ms;
}
#startBtn:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
#startBtnHvr {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all ease 0ms;
}
.startBtn {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
/* style.css */

body {
  background-image: url("background.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}
#startMnu {
  display: none;
  padding: 280px 180px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(86, 11, 3, .8), rgba(4, 74, 100, .8));
  /* Standard syntax */
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Online OS</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="ico_default.png">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="effects.js"></script>
  <link href="effects.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="sheet1">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="sheet1">
</head>

<body>
  <img id="startBtn" class="startBtn" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg/2000px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png" alt="" />
  <img id="startBtnHvr" class="startBtn" src="http://cdnl.accucutcraft.com/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/C/R/CR210.jpg" alt="" />
  <div id="startMnu">
    <h2 style=" float:left; position:absolute; margin-left:-95px; margin-top:-270px;" class="rename">Popup<h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I mean, slight errors though in snippet.

Comment: try this `$(".startBtn").click(function() {
 $(".startBtn").fadeToggle(200);
 $("#startMnu").toggle(200);
});
$(":not(.startBtn)").click(function() {
 alert('clickOff');
});`

Comment: If you want to hide you can just do `$("#startMnu").hide();`

Comment: $("body").clickOff( use id of a div instead of body

Comment: @SiddP It still says I'm clicking off.  Poria: That coulc work, but what if I click out of that div? Would it not work? It depends where it is also.

Comment: As simple as I can think of have a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown) . If your requirement is more specific please create a fiddle.

Comment: It's good, I just don't want it to close when you press a button in the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(".startBtn").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $("#startMenu").slideToggle("slow");
});

$("#startMenu").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$("body").click(function() {
  $("#startMenu").slideUp("slow");
});
```

```css
#startMenu {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="startBtn">Menu</button>
<br><br>
<div id="startMenu">startMnu</div>
```

Comment: It's good, but clicking on the menu "popup" also deactivates it. I was planning to have buttons on it.

Comment: It works, but not when I copy it to my code. Only works in this snippet.

Comment: Can I add slide effects to this also?

Comment: This is not a good way of doing this, as you will have a huge number of unnecessary calls every time the body is clicked.

Comment: is there any other way to do so?

Comment: Can I test for the menu toggled, to do a css hover action?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a event listener on html to hide it and use stopPropagation() to ignore that one when clicking on .startBtn

```
$('html').click(function() {
    alert('clickOff'); 
});

$(".startBtn").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".startBtn").fadeToggle(200); 
    $("#startMnu").toggle(200);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to avoid unneccessary event handling is to bind the body click inside the menu click, like so:

```
//persist your current menu state
var open = false;

function clickOn() {

    //force open the menu rather than toggle
    //so you are in control of the state
    $(".startBtn").fadeOut(200);
    $("#startMnu").fadeIn(200);

    open = true;

    //bind the body click
    $("body").on("click.menu", function(event) {
        clickOff(event);
    });
}

function clickOff() {
    $(".startBtn").fadeIn(200);
    $("#startMnu").fadeOut(200);

    open = false;

    //unbind the body click so it doesn't happen when the menu is closed
    $("body").unbind("click.menu");
}

$(".startBtn").click(function(e) {
    //stop the event bubbling up to the body
    e.stopPropagation();

    //check the current state
    open ? clickOff() : clickOn();
});
```

Comment: If thats all the Jquery I need, it doesn't work. I'm still learning it, and if I need to add the op part of the jsfiddle to to to work.

Comment: should work, it might just have been because the body was not 100%. Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tHCUB/132/

Comment: This assumes that what you were looking for is that clicking on the element triggers an open or close function, whilst clicking anywhere not on the element triggers a close function whilst the element is open, but otherwise does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".startBtn").click(function() { 
    $(".startBtn").fadeToggle(200);
    $("#startMnu").toggle(200);
}); 

$("body").click(function(event) {
    if(!$(event.target).closest('#startMnu').length && !$(event.target).closest('.startBtn').length) {
       $(".startBtn").fadeToggle(200);
        $("#startMnu").toggle(200);
    }
});
```

```css
.menu {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 60px;
}
#startMnu {
  background: #ffc501;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  width: 320px;
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

#startMnu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
}

#startMnu li a:hover {
  background: #ffe501;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="menu">
  <button class="startBtn">Opener</button>
  <ul id="startMnu">
     <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Menu Item 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yeah, but the button hides, and the body toggles it also.